# Burn a MP4 file with SRT subtitles

Tags: video, mp4, dvd, .srt

I have a movie and I want to burn it on a DVD, but I don't know how I do it and what the best options are. I want the DVD be able to play on PlayStation 4.
I have a movie in MP4 format and the subtitles are in SRT format. Are you able to tell me what the best programs are? I have installed Nero 2015, but I can't figure out how to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most HW players that can play mp4/avi/mkv/etc files-in-a-directory will load external-file subtitles if you just put them in the same directory as the video.  Burn it to a data DVD, or put it on a USB stick, and you're done.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I downloaded DVD flick and made a movie with added subtitles and it worked on my PS4.

Answer (score 0):

There is free software like DVD Flick and DVDStyler, but video on a DVD is limited to 720 Pixel in width (less than HD ready with 1280 Pixel in width) and as the video has to be reencoded you will allways loose quality, so I would also recommend to first try it with an USB-Stick or a data DVD.